# Looping Background in Unity

Tags: c#, unity

I am currently learning C# with Unity 2D but I have come across an issue after following a tutorial.

I am trying to get my camera to follow my player within the game but also to get my background looping so I dont have to have it miles long. I have added a boxcollider2D to outside left edge of the camera to pick up the background and then loop it to the right hand side before the camera gets there but for some reason it chucks it quite far to the right so I have areas with nothing showing but the player.

The only difference from the tutorial is that he was using 6 panels of background/ground whereas I am only using 1 big background sprite and 1 long ground sprite.

Heres my code for my looper;

```
public class BGLooper : MonoBehaviour {

    int numBGPanels = 2;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider){

        float widthOfBGObject = ((BoxCollider2D)collider).size.x;

        Vector3 pos = collider.transform.position;

        pos.x += widthOfBGObject * numBGPanels - widthOfBGObject / 4f;

        collider.transform.position = pos;

    }
}
```

Please help me so I can carry on creating my game :)

Comment: Sorry guys i also wanted to say that as the looper progresses through the scene it increases in speed rapidly, how i can i maintain a constant speed so the player doesn't have to catch up.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to GD.SE - please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310130/unity-game-deveopment-looping-background) questions. If you would like questions moved between sites (where appropriate) please flag for a moderator.

Comment: You keep talking about a tutorial in your post, yet I see no link to it. Would you please edit a link towards it?

Comment: sorry about the two questions :( the link is on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7Nz_AulrrA video's 1-7 but this is the video about the background - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPEqunWUeuQ

Comment: Just wanna clear things up. Are you translating both your camera and the background in your game? The phrase `before the camera gets there` makes me wonder.

Comment: I apologize i am not great at trying to explain this. I have resolved the issue by adding multiple backgrounds and then moving my BGLooper further to the left which seems to work fine